# Set Content Offset for Scroll View

Tags: ios, xcode, ios5, ios6

Is there a way to set the offset of a scroll view that is inside a view controller programatically?

I have to set it based on different conditions.

Comment: check the [reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIScrollView_Class/Reference/UIScrollView.html) and [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5200248/programatically-control-uiscrollview) on SO.

Answer (score 12):

yes you can set the contentOffset of your scrollview-
 And the code will be like this -

```
if(your Condition)
{
    [scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0,-50) animated:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Yes,

```
scrollView.contentOffset
```

**Documentation:** http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIScrollView_Class/Reference/UIScrollView.html